# How to use getPixel, getColor Method in lua

Tags: lua, gideros

Can someone please show me the correct way to use getPixel and getColor in lua.
I tried

```
 pix = 5; piy = 5;
 getPixel(pix, piy) --getColor(pix, piy)

 image:getPixel(pix, piy) --image:getColor(pix, piy)
```

...and I just can't figure out what lua is complaining about.

**error**:
 *attempt to call global 'getPixel' (a nil value)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone please show me the correct way to use getPixel and
>   getColor in lua.

Lua does not provide a function to get pixels or colours. Again, as in your earlier questions, this is something you'll find in the Gideros manual.

> `getPixel(pix, piy) --image:getColor(pix, piy)`
>
> ...and I just can't figure out what lua is complaining about.
>
> **error**: attempt to call global 'getPixel' (a nil value)

Lua complains about you calling a nil value. There is no variable named getPixel in your global environment.

So once again open the Gideros manual:
http://docs.giderosmobile.com/reference/gideros

Then for example click Pixel in the left menu:
http://docs.giderosmobile.com/reference/gideros/Pixel#Pixel